# How to limit data from 2 dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**Problem**

I have 50 entries my database and it has 3 columns called `favourites`,`timestamp` and `comments`. Using these 3 values I need to get some data with a limitation. If there are 10 rows after summation the `comments`, `favourites` and the `timestamp` is **today**, The query with limit of 20 should be fetched today's top 10 posts and yesterday's top 10 posts. I already did the following query.

```
SELECT post_id, (comments + favourites) AS rank FROM post GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 20
```

How may I solve this problem?

**My updated query**

```
SELECT post.*, (no_of_comments + no_of_favourites) AS rank 
FROM post 
GROUP BY post_id 
ORDER BY rank DESC, timestamp LIMIT 10

+---------+----------------------------+------+
| post_id | timestamp                  | rank |
+---------+----------------------------+------+
|       8 | 2016-08-29 15:32:26.000000 |  346 |
|      14 | 2016-08-29 15:33:23.000000 |  178 |
|      11 | 2016-08-29 15:33:05.000000 |   98 |
|      10 | 2016-08-29 15:32:38.000000 |   88 |
|      12 | 2016-08-29 15:33:10.000000 |   87 |
|       6 | 2016-08-29 15:32:12.000000 |   84 |
|      13 | 2016-08-29 15:33:16.000000 |   66 |
|      15 | 2016-08-29 15:33:28.000000 |   60 |
|       5 | 2016-08-29 15:32:05.000000 |   57 |
|       7 | 2016-08-29 15:32:19.000000 |   54 |
```

In this, latest date records should be ordered as newest first. `rank = (comments + favourites)`

Comment: why you not use a order by timestamp desc ?

Comment: should be the greatest sum of comments + favourites should be comes first. And if the today's posts are over the rest of it should be from yesterday.

Comment: can you paste some example over here in your question for better understand

Comment: updated the question

Comment: `SELECT post.*, (no_of_comments + no_of_favourites) AS rank 
FROM post 
GROUP BY post_id 
ORDER BY rank DESC, timestamp desc LIMIT 10` Try this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the latest timestamp should be at the top. latest date's top ranked posts should be at the top.

Comment: You are being very unclear, please check my answer and comment there if it is not fixing your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to select the top 10 of each day, ordered by day (from newest to oldest) and then rank (from top to bottom)?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to do that